# Как узнать id пользователя в Active Directory

Tags: windows, windows-server

Как в AD узнать id пользователя компа? Сеть из 50 компов, каждый имеет имя и свой id, который прописан в AD. Вот и как его можно узнать через AD?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте этот [скрипт](http://blog.shakirov.com/2006/10/19/skript_dlja_poluchenija_informatsii_o_polzovateljax_domena/), в него, правда, надо внести небольшие изменения... А ещё была утилита, не помню точного названия, но [здесь](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter) вы точно найдёте что-то подобное.